# Styling components in react

Tags: reactjs

I am building my first react website, and i wanted to ask what the best practice is when it comes to styling. Does it make more sense to make a different stylesheet for each component or it makes more sense to have the styles for all components in a single stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to have a common style sheet - styles used between components. In addition, anything component specific I would have in it's own style sheet to avoid polluting your shared style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#what-is-css-in-js):

> React does not have an opinion about how styles are defined; if in doubt, **a good starting point is to define your styles in a separate *.css file** as usual and refer to them using [className](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname).

For a review of React styling methods, take a look at this (slightly older) presentation by Max Stoiber - [Styling React.JS applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19gqsBc_Cx0). It's a couple of years old but worth a look.

[CSS-in-JS](https://mxstbr.com/thoughts/css-in-js/) has been the most appealing to me. There are numerous techniques/packages, so here is a [useful comparison](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js).